# Plot projective curves

Tags: graphing-functions, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space, spheres

Do you know any website, app or program that can plot curves in the projective plane?

I know the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2 \mathbb{R}$ can be visualized as a sphere with the antipodal points identified, and I was thinking that seeing curves on the projective plane as (couples of) curves on a sphere $S^2$ could make us be able to plot them. Has anyone created yet a way to do it?